# ionic 2 - run app on ipad device

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins

What could be causing this error? I am using Xcode version 8.

> /Users/package/workspace/apps-72dfa722-8/cordova/platforms/ios/dcc-mobile-sample/Plugins/cordova.plugins.diagnostic/Diagnostic.m:826:25: error: no known class method for selector 'isPedometerEventTrackingAvailable'
>       return [CMPedometer isPedometerEventTrackingAvailable];
>                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Users/package/workspace/apps-72dfa722-8/cordova/platforms/ios/dcc-mobile-sample/Plugins/cordova.plugins.diagnostic/Diagnostic.m:826:12: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'id' from a function with result type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') [-Wint-conversion]
>       return [CMPedometer isPedometerEventTrackingAvailable];
>              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   2 warnings and 1 error generated.

Comment: Looks like issue is with accessing iOS CMPedometer/Core Motion API from Cordova.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with [cordova-plugin-diagnostic](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin), the latest version of which adds support for new functionality in iOS 10 - see [this issue](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/153).

- Make double sure you are building with XCode 8 for iOS 10
- Ensure that you're using an up-to-date version of [cordova-ios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-ios) platform - latest is `@4.3.1`. Check with `cordova platform ls`
- Ensure that Core Motion framework is present in your Xcode project - if not, add it.
- Try building and running the [plugin example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin-example)